# Receiving ServletContext Into A Plain Java Class?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, realpath

I'm just starting out learning some JSP and servlets today and was wondering if it's possible to get the session's `ServletContext` as a variable and pass it to a plain Java class?  If so, how may I do that?

My simple servlet:

```
public class myServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 

                //How do I receive the servlet context below in a plain Java class?
                ServletContext sc = session.getServletContext();
                request.setAttribute("sc", sc); 
        }
}
```

My Java class is just a plain one:

```
public class myClass extends HttpServlet {

   //I want to be able to use the ServletContext as a variable that is passed from myServlet class into this one.

}
```

In `myClass` I want to be able to use it to get the real path file of a file within my project:

`ServletContext sc
String path = sc.getRealPath(...)`

**EDIT:**  Can I do something like this in `myServlet` servlet?:

`String realPath = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/myFile");`

But then how do I pass this `realPath` variable into `myClass` so I can use it there instead of in `myServlet`?

Comment: why are your extending `public class myClass extends HttpServlet` ?

Comment: The guy tutoring me told me to put it.  When I asked him, he didn't really have an answer.  Like I said, I just started learning servlets and JSP today

Comment: maybe a xy problem - what are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a class

   `public class MyClass {....}`
2. Have a variable of type `ServletContext`

   `private ServletContext myContext;`
3. Set value through Constructor or setter

   `void setContext (ServletContext sc) {myContext = sc;}`
4. Use it

   `myContext.get....("xxx");`

**Edit**

You can use this class from your servlet as

```
doPost (....) {

   ....
    ServletContext sc = session.getServletContext();
   MyClass mc = new MyClass ();
   mc.setContext (sc);

 // now the context is **in** the MyClass instance - how you use it is up to you.
```

Comment: If I put my setter `void setcontext(...){...}` in `myClass`, where is the `sc` coming from?

Comment: You construct and call this code from your `Servlet`

Comment: I should code my setter and getter for `myContext` in `myServlet`?

Comment: Huh? Which step 1-4 indicates that you should do that?

Comment: Your reply said so.

Comment: If you mean using the `myContext` in `myServlet` by calling it from `myClass`, I actually want the opposite if it's possible.

Comment: All I want is to know if there is a way to bring the session's `ServletContext` from `myServlet` into `myClass`.  I don't want to call a servlet context into `myServlet`.

Comment: I have no idea where you think your are going to use this plain Java class from, **but** before you can use, you need to instantiate it - I am assuming from the servlet (because your code gives me no other idea).  So based upon this see my edited code.

Comment: As I said before *maybe a xy problem - what are you really trying to achieve?*

Comment: ok, when I do this does this mean that the `myContext` (you named yours `context`) variable within `myClass` now has the same `ServletContext` value as `myServlet` ?

Comment: `MyClass::context == myServlet ::sc` so yes

Comment: er James - are you there?